# How to handle existing external storage files on app upgrade in Android?

Tags: android, upgrade, android-sdcard, file-copying

An android app is getting updated after a long time. It was using external storage permission (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) to save the user selected files and images in a directory that the app created `/sdcard/emulated/0/myapp`

Now when the upgrade is getting pushed, Google has updated the file access framework and now restricted access to the external storage.

`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is restricted by Google policy.

How can we move the existing app files in sdcard to the Android/data folder while upgrading the app so that the app has access to the existing files created in the older version?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your app still has access. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick the directory.

Comment: @blackapps I have tried it and it gives a URI. I was not able to get all the folder contents (sub-folders and files) with that. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, How to list the files is basic knowledge using storage access framework.